# Filter based on date range picked using Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, date, alpine.js

Im trying to filter the directors `$inactiveDirectors` who were active during the selected `fromDate`  and the `toDate`.
Directors will be active from their effective date (`director.effective_date`) to their resigned/removed date (`director.release_date`). And if the user did not pick a `toDate` it will be assumed to as the current date.

The function:

```
 function loadDirectors() {


    return {
        fromDate: ""
        , toDate: ""
        , fromDateObj: null
        , toDateObj: null
        , directorsList: @json($inactiveDirectors)
        , get filteredDirectors() {
            if (this.fromDate === "") {
                return this.directorsList;
            }

            this.fromDateObj = new Date(this.fromDate);


            if (this.toDate === "") {
                this.toDateObj = null;
            } else {
                this.toDateObj = new Date(this.toDate);
            }

            return this.directorsList.filter((director) => {
                let effective_date_obj = new Date(director.effective_date);
                let release_date = new Date(director.release_date);

                if (this.fromDateObj.getTime() < effective_date_obj.getTime()) {
                    if (this.toDateObj) {
                        if (this.toDateObj.getTime() > release_date.getTime()) {
                            return director;
                        } else {
                            return director;
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to filter using Alpine.js with no luck yet. Appreciate if you could find a way to resolve this.

The UI:
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it. For your reference:

```
function loadDirectors() {
        return {
            fromDate: ""
            , toDate: ""
            , fromDateObj: null
            , toDateObj: null
            , directorsList: @json($inactiveDirectors)
            , get filteredDirectors() {
                if (this.fromDate === "" && this.toDate === "") {

                    return this.directorsList;
                }

                // if toDate not selected
                if (this.toDate === "") {
                    this.toDateObj = null;
                } else {
                    this.toDateObj = new Date(this.toDate);
                }

                // if fromDate not selected
                if (this.fromDate === "") {
                    this.fromDateObj = null;
                } else {
                    this.fromDateObj = new Date(this.fromDate);
                }



                return this.directorsList.filter((director) => {
                    // director effective date object
                    let effectiveDate = director.effective_date;
                    const eArray = effectiveDate.split("/");
                    let effectiveDay = eArray[0];
                    let effectiveMonth = eArray[1];
                    let effectiveYear = eArray[2];
                    const effective_date = effectiveMonth + '/' + effectiveDay + '/' + effectiveYear;
                    let effectiveDateObj = new Date(effective_date);

                    // director release date object
                    let releaseDate = director.release_date;
                    const rArray = releaseDate.split("/");
                    let releaseDay = rArray[0];
                    let releaseMonth = rArray[1];
                    let releaseYear = rArray[2];
                    const release_date = releaseMonth + '/' + releaseDay + '/' + releaseYear;
                    let releaseDateObj = new Date(release_date);


                    let shouldReturn = true;
                    if (this.fromDateObj && this.fromDateObj > effectiveDateObj) {
                        shouldReturn = false;
                    }

                    if (this.toDateObj) {
                        if (this.fromDateObj) {
                            if (releaseDateObj < this.fromDateObj || releaseDateObj > this.toDateObj)
                                shouldReturn = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (shouldReturn) {
                        return director;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).